# Custom Jquery mobile for Hijax and ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

is there a way to customize jquery mobile to include all the functionality related to hijax and ajax?

I'm using the below builder. By selecting all the navigation options (on the tool) it will automatically load the dependencies but after testing the custom js and css the hijax doesn't work.

[jQuery Mobile Download Builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/)

The normal release works fine but i don't want it to customize all the UI as usual on jquery mobile. And i also don't need any other widget than navigation (hijax, ajax) on **links** and **forms**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By mistake I didn't import a CSS custom file generated by the jquery mobile builder tool.
The problem had an easy solution:

Ensure that you require the following CSS files:

```
jquery.mobile.custom.theme.css
jquery.mobile.custom.structure.css
```

At the css folder create a a new one called images 
There you should have the loader.gif

Also, at the heading of the document, after the css, ensure that jquery is loaded followed by jquery.mobile and the custom build.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
            <script src="js/jquery.mobile.custom.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
```